# How do I send a struct from a UDP client to server?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm having some trouble sending a struct of data from a UDP client to a UDP server. I'm not sure what the problem is exactly. I have a source file responsible for setting up a UDP client and defining the function to send data:

UDPClient.cpp

```
#include "UDPClient.h"

UDPClient::UDPClient(unsigned short port) {

    // UDP Client sends messages to UDP server on this port.
    this->port = port;

    // Create UDP socket file descriptor.
    // int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Socket creation failed. socket() system call returned an error." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Zero memory of serv_addr struct.
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

    // Configure server address structure.
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
}

void UDPClient::send(const char* bytes) {
    // ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
    sendto(sockfd, bytes, strlen(bytes), MSG_CONFIRM, (const sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    std::cout << "Message Sent." << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the header file:

UDPClient.h

```
#ifndef UDPCLIENT_H
#define UDPCLIENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

class UDPClient
{
public:
    UDPClient(unsigned short);
    void send(const char*);
private:
    unsigned short port;
    int sockfd;
    sockaddr_in serv_addr;
};

#endif
```

Then I have the source file responsible for declaring a struct and sending the data of the struct by using the reinterpret_cast() function to change it to a byte string.

sendData.cpp

```
#include "UDPClient.h"

struct myStruct {
    int a;
    double b;
    float c;
};

int main() {
    unsigned short port = 22842;
    UDPClient client(port);

    myStruct data;
    data.a = 1;
    data.b = 2.0;
    data.c = 3.0;

    const char* dataInBytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data);
    client.send(dataInBytes);
}
```

I also have a very similar setup for setting up the UDP server and defining the function to receive data from it.

UDPServer.cpp

```
#include "UDPServer.h"

UDPServer::UDPServer(unsigned short port) {
    
    // UDP Server binds to an address on this port.
    this->port = port;
    
    // Create UDP socket file descriptor.
    // socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Socket creation failed. socket() system call returned an error." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Zero memory of serv_addr struct.
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

    // Configure server address structure.
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    // Bind the socket to the server address.
    // int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
    if (bind(sockfd, (sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Binding socket failed. bind() system call returned an error." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);
}

char* UDPServer::receive() {
    // ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
    int n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char*) buffer, MAXLINE, MSG_CONFIRM, (sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &cli_len);
    return buffer;  
}
```

Here is the header file:

UDPServer.h

```
#ifndef UDPSERVER_H
#define UDPSERVER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAXLINE 1024

class UDPServer
{
public:
    UDPServer(unsigned short);
    char* receive();
private:
    unsigned short port;
    int sockfd;
    sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t cli_len;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
};

#endif
```

Now I am trying to receive the data contained within the struct by implementing the UDP Server and copying the memory of the byte string it receives back into a struct:

receiveData.cpp

```
#include "UDPServer.h"

struct myStruct {
    int a;
    double b;
    float c;
};

int main() {
    unsigned short port = 22842;
    UDPServer server(port);

    myStruct data;

    char* bytes = server.receive();

    memcpy(&data, bytes, sizeof(data));

    std::cout << "int a: " << data.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double b: " << data.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "float c: " << data.c << std::endl;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
int a: 1
double b: 2.0
float c: 3.0
```

but instead I am getting:

```
int a: 1
double b: 0
float c: 0
```

Why is the struct data not being passed correctly? What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You can `bind()` to `INADDR_ANY` (`0.0.0.0`), but you can't send to `INADDR_ANY`, you have to send to an actual IP address.  More importantly, `strlen()` does not work on binary data that may contain `0x00` bytes in it (as yours does).

Answer (score 1):

A struct is not a null-terminated string, you can't use `strlen()` to get its length. You need to use `sizeof data`, and pass this as an argument to `send()`.

```
void UDPClient::send(const char* bytes, size_t len) {
    // ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
    sendto(sockfd, bytes, len, MSG_CONFIRM, (const sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    std::cout << "Message Sent." << std::endl;
}
```

```
int main() {
    unsigned short port = 22842;
    UDPClient client(port);

    myStruct data;
    data.a = 1;
    data.b = 2.0;
    data.c = 3.0;

    const char* dataInBytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data);
    client.send(dataInBytes, sizeof data);
}
```

Comment: Just be carefully of alignment padding in the `struct`.  Better to *serialize* the `struct` data into a byte array, and then send that instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think that should be a problem, `sizeof` includes padding. However, sending binary data over the network can be a problem if the sender and receiver do not use the same representation.

Comment: I know `sizeof` includes padding, that wasn't my point. Padding is compiler-specific, it is not a good idea to include padding in transmitted data. So yes, sender and receiver have to agree on the formatting of the data, and that is not easy to guarantee over a network connection without a formal design.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Compilers have to follow the ABI of the OS. So if the sender and receiver are the same architecture/OS, it will be compatible.

Comment: No, actually they are not *required* to, and no, they are not *guaranteed* to be. You can't *guarantee* compatibility across compilers. It is very easy to tweak a compiler's alignment settings to introduce incompatibilities between compilers, even on the same machine. That is why you should formalize the design of the data being exchanged. Use a format that is not subject to compiler settings or platform idioms.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course they have to. How else could you call system library functions if your compiler is different from the one used to compile the OS. That's the whole point of an ABI, it ensures interoperability between compilers.

Comment: I can set a compiler to 4-byte alignment, and set another compiler to 8-byte alignment, and they will both be able to make many system calls just fine. But the former one won't be able to use OS structs that require 8-byte alignment, and the two compilers won't be able to exchange structs with each other. But whatever.  Using structs for UDP data risks ODR and Strict-alias violations, so really shouldn't be done at all, even if they appear to "just work". But the answer to the OP's question has already been given, so let's move on.